# pytest setup_class method and db access

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-django

```
import pytest
from . import utilization

pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db
some_period = 'test' 

@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestUtilization(object):
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(self):
        self.period = some_period
        self.metric = utilization.Utilization(period=self.period)
        print('setup')

    def test_get_query_params(self, tprint):
        """Should return dict with start/end keys of datetime values"""
        # assert self.xxx == some_period
        tprint(self.period)
        tprint(self.metric)

    def test_call(self, tprint):
        """Test that we have desired fields and index of the metric"""
        pass
```

and I get this:

```
E       Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" 
mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
```

#### How do I fix this?

Ideally I need setup_class to work only once, and the following line
`self.metric = utilization.Utilization(period=self.period)` require DB access

Dmitry

Comment: `pytest-django` is not meant to be used with classes. If you are tied to classes, I'd recommend to use `django.test.TestCase` and company. Use `pytest-django` when you write test functions, setting them up with fixtures. If you insist on coupling `pytest-django` fixtures with `xUnit` test classes, you will need to write own db unblocker fixture, class-scoped, as `pytest-django` doesn't offer db unlocking on class level.